# Cannot download certain texts from website

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to download all the last statements from the [Death Row Website](http://www.tdcj.state.tx.us/death_row/dr_executed_offenders.html). Basic outline is like this
1. The info from the site gets imported in an sqlite database, prison.sqlite
2. Based on the names in the table, I generate unique URL's for each name, to get their last statements.
3. The program checks each generated URL, if URL is OK, it checks for the last statement. This statement gets downloaded to the database prison.sqlite (still 2 do).

This is my code:

```
import sqlite3
import csv
import re
import urllib2
from urllib2 import Request, urlopen, URLError
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import string
URLS = ["http://www.tdcj.state.tx.us/death_row/dr_info/hernandezramontorreslast.html",
    "http://www.tdcj.state.tx.us/death_row/dr_info/garciafrankmlast.html",
    "http://www.tdcj.state.tx.us/death_row/dr_info/martinezdavidlast999173.html",
    "http://www.tdcj.state.tx.us/death_row/dr_info/moselydaroycelast.html",
    "http://www.tdcj.state.tx.us/death_row/dr_info/martinezdavidlast999288.html",
    "http://www.tdcj.state.tx.us/death_row/dr_info/hernandezadophlast.html",
    "http://www.tdcj.state.tx.us/death_row/dr_info/carterrobertanthonylast.html",
    "http://www.tdcj.state.tx.us/death_row/dr_info/livingstoncharleslast.html",
    "http://www.tdcj.state.tx.us/death_row/dr_info/gentrykennethlast.html",
    "http://www.tdcj.state.tx.us/death_row/dr_info/gentrykennethlast.html",
    "http://www.tdcj.state.tx.us/death_row/dr_info/wilkersonrichardlast.html",
    "http://www.tdcj.state.tx.us/death_row/dr_info/hererraleonellast.html",]

conn = sqlite3.connect('prison.sqlite')
conn.text_factory = str
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS prison")
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Prison ( Execution text, link1 text, Statements text, LastName text, Firstname text, TDCJNumber text, Age integer, date text, race text, county text)")
conn.commit()


csvfile = open("prisonfile.csv","rb")
creader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ",")
for t in creader:
    cur.execute('INSERT INTO  Prison VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)', t, )

for column in cur.execute("SELECT LastName, Firstname FROM prison"):
    lastname = column[0]
    firstname = column[1]
    name = lastname+firstname
    CleanName = name.translate(None, ",.!-@'#$" "")
    CleanName = CleanName.replace(" ", "")
    CleanName = CleanName.replace("III","")
    CleanName = re.sub("Sr","",CleanName)
    CleanName = re.sub("Jr","",CleanName)
    CleanName = CleanName.lower()
    Baseurl = "http://www.tdcj.state.tx.us/death_row/dr_info/"
    Link = Baseurl+CleanName+"last.html"
    URLS.append(Link)


    for Link in URLS:
        try:
            r = requests.get(Link)
            r.raise_for_status()
            print "URL OK", Link
            document = urllib2.urlopen(Link)
            html = document.read()
            soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
            Statement = soup.find(text="Last Statement:").findNext('p').contents[0]
            print Statement
            continue
        except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as err:
            print err
            print "Offender has made no statement.", Link
            #cur.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO prison(Statements) VALUES(?)"), (Statement, )

csvfile.close()
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

When running the program I get:

```
C:\python>prison.py
URL OK http://www.tdcj.state.tx.us/death_row/dr_info/hernandezramontorreslast.html
Can you hear me? Did I ever tell you, you have dad's eyes? I've noticed that in the last couple of days. I'm sorry for putting you through all this. Tell everyone I love them. It was good seeing the kids. I love them all; tell mom, everybody. I am very sorry for all of the pain. Tell Brenda I love her. To everybody back on the row, I know you're going through a lot over there. Keep fighting, don't give up everybody.
URL OK http://www.tdcj.state.tx.us/death_row/dr_info/garciafrankmlast.html
Thank you, Jesus Christ. Thank you for your blessing. You are above the president. And know it is you, Jesus Christ, that is performing this miracle in my life. Hallelujah, Holy, Holy, Holy. For this reason I was born and raised. Thank you for this, my God is a God of Salvation. Only through you, Jesus Christ, people will see that you're still on the throne. Hallelujah, Holy, Holy, Holy. I invoke Your name. Thank you, Yahweh, thank you Jesus Christ. Hallelujah, Amen. Thank you, Warden.
URL OK http://www.tdcj.state.tx.us/death_row/dr_info/martinezdavidlast999173.html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python\prison.py", line 60, in <module>
    Statement = soup.find(text="Last Statement:").findNext('p').contents[0]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'findNext'
```

First two statements are fine, but after that program crashes. Looking at the page source of the URL where the error occurs, I see:
(only relevant data)

```
<div class="return_to_div"></div>
<h1>Offender Information</h1>
<h2>Last Statement</h2>
<p class="text_bold">Date of Execution:</p>
<p> February 4, 2009</p>
<p class="text_bold"> Offender:</p>
<p> Martinez, David</p>
<p class="text_bold"> Last Statement:</p>
<p> Yes, nothing I can say can change the past. I am asking for forgiveness. Saying sorry is not going to change anything. I hope one day you can find peace. I am sorry for all of the pain that I have caused you for all those years. There is nothing else I can say, that can help you. Mija, I love you. Sis, Cynthia, and Sandy, keep on going and it will be O.K. I am sorry to put you through this as well. I can't change the past. I hope you find peace and know that I love you. I am sorry. I am sorry and I can't change it.  </p>
```

What could be causing this issue. Do I have to change something on this line?:

```
Statement = soup.find(text="Last Statement:").findNext('p').contents[0]
```

Feel free to share improvements to my code. Right now I want to get everything working before I will make it more robust.

For the people wondering about the list with URL's in it: It is due to some bugs on the death row site. Sometimes the URL differs from [lastname][firstname]last.html. I added them manually for now.

Comment: You're searching for "Last Statement:", but the actual text is " Last Statement:"  (with a leading space).

Comment: Try `soup.find(string=re.compile("Last Statement:"))`.  This should ignore leading (or trailing) spaces.  You'll also have to import the `re` module.

Comment: Hi @JohnGordon. Thanks for your reply. 
it results in another error being:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\python\prison.py", line 60, in <module>
        Statement = soup.find(string=re.compile("Last Statement:")).findNext('p').contents[0]
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'findNext'

I'll check it out. Probably some sort of wrong syntax. Nicely spotted by the way!!

Comment: I think I found it:

    pattern = re.compile("Last Statement:")
    Statement = soup.find(text=pattern).findNext('p').contents[0]